# How can configure ws-security with CXF or anything missing

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, ws-security

I'm trying to create a web service with WS-Security so far I have configured the following:

**`cxf.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <bean id="logIn" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    <bean id="logOut" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />

    <bean class="com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios.NodoCentralImpl"
        id="NodoCentralImpl" />
    <jaxws:endpoint address="/NodoCentralImplWS" id="NodoCentralImplWS"
        implementor="#NodoCentralImpl">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

    <bean class="com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios.HelloWorldImpl"
        id="HelloWorldImpl" />
    <jaxws:endpoint address="/HelloWorldImplWS" id="HelloWorldImplWS"
        implementor="#HelloWorldImpl">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>

<!-- ?? -->
        <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                        <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios.ClientPasswordCallback" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

The CallBack class that would control the user and password is this:

The idea is to control against BD and the execution grant or deny.

**`ClientPasswordCallback.java`**

```
package com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, 
            UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
        System.out.println("pc.getPassword() " + pc.getPassword());
        System.out.println("pc.getIdentifier() " + pc.getIdentifier());
        if ("joe".equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {
            pc.setPassword("joespassword");
        } // else {...} - can add more users, access DB, etc.
    }
}
```

The **`web.xml`** file is configured as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>capa_datos_nodo</display-name>

    <description>Roo generated capa_datos_nodo application</description>


    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>capa_datos_nodo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>capa_datos_nodo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/uncaughtException</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
    </error-page>

        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config-location</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/conf_cxf_context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servicios/datos/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This class is for the web service has only one method of return is only for testing

**`HelloWorldImpl.java`**

```
package com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutInterceptors;

//Service Implementation Bean
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.palominocia.capa_datos_nodo.servicios.HelloWorld")
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
@OutInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsctx;

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString() {

    MessageContext mctx = wsctx.getMessageContext();
    System.out.println("header "+mctx);
    //get detail from request headers
        Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        List userList = (List) http_headers.get("Username");
        List passList = (List) http_headers.get("Password");

        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        if(userList!=null){
            //get username
            username = userList.get(0).toString();
        }

        if(passList!=null){
            //get password
            password = passList.get(0).toString();
        }
        System.out.println("userList "+userList);
        System.out.println("passList "+passList);
        //Should validate username and password with database
        if (username.equals("mkyong") && password.equals("password")){
            return "Hello World JAX-WS - Valid User!";
        }else{
            return "Unknown User!";
        }

    }   
}
```

Previously used for authentication by the head but I am proving the library ws-security.

What happens is that if I create the web client with netbeans and I run it just jumps me the following **error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An Error was discovered processing the <wsse: Security> header.
```

The client is written so:

```
HelloWorldImplService serv = new HelloWorldImplService();
        HelloWorld port = serv.getHelloWorldImplPort();
        System.out.println(" *** " + port.getHelloWorldAsString());
```

I built the program according to the resources found online, before adding ws-security running properly and that I may be missing.

Sorry for the English but I'm not good at writing

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information than just a single error message. Turn on DEBUG logging + it will probably tell you what the problem is. If not then attach the log here.

Colm.